# Undefined control sequence \State \COMMENT

Tags: algorithms

Undefined control sequence `\State \COMMENT`.

The manual clearly state that I can use the `\comment`. I use `\usepackage{algpseudocode} \usepackage{algorithm}`. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,subfigure}

\title{{Bachelor Thesis\\[0.5em]}
       {\bf \huge Road Inventory\\Detection and Recognition\\[0.5em]}
       {\bf Weekly Report 3}}
\author{Poul Sørensen. s093294}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5mm}


\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[draft,english]{fixme}                   %Pakke til at skrive marginnoter under arbejdet. Skift draft til final når der skal printes. Brug 'fxnote{}','fxwarning', 'fxerror' eller 'fxfatal' alt efter behov.
%\fxsetup{layout=margin}                            %Footnote anbefales som option - men er ikke specielt praktisk?

\newcommand{\openCV}{\texttt{OpenCV}~}
\newcommand{\cpp}{\texttt{C++}~}
\usepackage{url}

% Different font in captions
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up,margin=7mm]{caption}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{rotating}

\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}

\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{quotationcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\definecolor{quotationmarkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.4,0.9}
% Double-line for start and end of epigraph.
\newcommand{\epiline}{\hrule \vskip -.2em \hrule}
% Massively humongous opening quotation mark.
\newcommand{\hugequote}{%
  \fontsize{42}{48}\selectfont \color{quotationmarkcolour} \textbf{``}
  \vskip -.5em
}

\newcounter{quotecounter}

% Beautify quotations.
\newcommand{\epigraph}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{quotecounter}
  \begin{flushright}
  \colorbox{quotationcolour}{%
    \parbox{.95\textwidth}{%
    \epiline \vskip 1em {\hugequote} \vskip -.5em
    \parindent 2.2em
    #1\begin{flushright}\textbf{Quote \thesection.\thequotecounter}~~ \textsc{#2}\end{flushright}
    \epiline
    }
  }
  \end{flushright}

}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
%\usepackage{program}
%\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\eqparbox{COMMENT}{\backslash\backslash #1}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
\section{Performance Measurement }
There exist a few methods for measure performance~\cite{Book:OpenCV}. First one of interest is \textit{cross-validation} and its close related technique of \textit{bootstrapping}. A great outline on the topic can be found online\footnote{www.faqs.org/fags/ai-fag/neural-nets/part3/section-12.html}.

Cross-validation involves splitting the data $\Phi $ into $k$ distinct subsets ${\Phi_1,\cdots,\Phi_{k-1},\Phi_k}$, training $k$ times on $k-1$ of the subsets and testing with left out set. The $k$ test results can then be averaged to a final score.


%\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}

\Procedure{CrossValidate}{$\Phi$}
\ForAll{$\phi \in {\Phi_1,\cdots,\Phi_{k-1},\Phi_k}$} 
    \State $model =$ Train($\Phi \setminus \phi$ )
    \ForAll{$s \in \phi$ }
        \State  \COMMENT{hej}
    \EndFor

\EndFor
\EndProcedure

\end{algorithmic} 
%\end{algorithm}


\section{Related Work}\fxnote{(intended for report.)}

\subsection{Machine Learning}
\input{../../"Report Parts"/MachineLearning/ML.tex}
\subsubsection{Prediction Trees}
\input{../../"Report Parts"/MachineLearning/PredictionTrees.tex}


\subsection{Colour Analysis}

\subsection{Decision Tree}

\subsection{Forest of Decision Trees}

\subsection{Hough Forest}

\newpage

\section*{Project status according to the study plan}

All under control. Report work is doing well.

\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{../../../../references}

\appendix
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it is needed; you should give a [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl).

Comment: Code examples should be *minimal*, not as lengthy as yours.

Comment: Please don't do cross-site posts. Moderators can migrate questions from stackoverflow to tex.se

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LaTeX is case sensitive it terms of control sequences. So, `\Comment` is different from `\COMMENT`, `\comment` and all other valid combinations. This is what you're after in terms of showing a comment - using `\Comment{...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \Procedure{CrossValidate}{$\Phi$}
    \ForAll{$\phi \in {\Phi_1,\cdots,\Phi_{k-1},\Phi_k}$} 
      \State $model =$ Train($\Phi \setminus \phi$ )
      \ForAll{$s \in \phi$ }
        \State \Comment{hej}
      \EndFor
    \EndFor
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

From the [`algorithmicx` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf) (section **2.4 Placing comments in sources**, p 4):

> Comments may be placed everywhere in the source using the `\Comment` macro ...

Comment: Somehow i got some manuals mixed up. \COMMENT was from program package.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one more thing which is also helpful.  sometimes you need to specify the place of your comment. so on the top of document

```
\newcommand{\Comment}[1]{{\hskip3em$\rightarrow$ #1}}
```

and inside the algorithm you could easily use

```
\Comment
```

and the results 
will appear like this

```
x → Here is a comment
```